# Pointers as a return value

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

If I made function that sums two variables and return the summing result through pointer.

What are the expected problems could happen from that algorithm ?

Comment: Undefined behavior because you return an address to a local variable.

Comment: Are you just asking about the "algorithm", or do you have any specific code that causes trouble? Because if you have code you should show it to us so we can help you solve the problem you're having with it.

Comment: Show some code so we don't need to guess what your problem is.

Comment: int* sum(int x, int y){ int z;  z=x+y;  int *p=&z;  return p;  }  what is the expected problems from that code?

Comment: @Eman:I have covered that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem if you do it like this:

```
void sum(int a, int b, int *res)
{
  *res = a+b;  
}
```

and for example call like:

```
 int x;
 sum(5, 6, &x);
```

But following is not correct:

```
int* sum(int a, int b)
{
  int *res;
  int x = a+b;
  res = &x;
  return res;// returning address of x - but x is not alive when function ends; don't do it
}
```

PS. you could also use `malloc`, store the result (`a+b`) in that memory (by assigning `a+b` to `*res`), and then return that pointer, but then the caller would need to free it.

Answer (score 2):

> the expected problems

- uninitialised pointer(s)

  ```
  void add(int a, int b, int * pc)
  {
    *pc = a + b;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int * pc;

    add(a, b, pc);

    ...
  ```

  Issue: `pc` points "nowhere".
- badly aligned memory

  ```
  void add(int a, int b, int * pc)
  {
    *pc = a + b;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    char c[sizeof (int)];

    add(a, b, c); /* or even add(a, b (int*) c); */

    ...
  ```

  Issue: Although large enough, the memory for `c` might not be aligned correctly to hold an `int`.
- invalid memory

  ```
  void add(int a, int b, int * pc)
  {
    int c = a + b;
    pc = &c;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int * pc;

    add(a, b, pc);

    ...
  ```

  Issue: On returning from `add()` `pc` points to invalid memory, as already deallocated, namely to `c` which lived on `add()`'s stack.

Answer (score 1):

If the result is on the stack (i.e. declared locally in your function), then the pointer will be pointing to a variable that will be overwritten once further function calls are made.

It might appear to work in some circumstances (i.e. immediately returning from the function and grabbing the value before further stack frames are pushed) - but generally speaking that's buggy / erroneous.